# Crash during cloud recording

Tags: crash, agora.io, agora-cloud-recording

I want to run an app (any of iOS/Android/RN etc.) with Agora's cloud recording using the golang backend: https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Cloud-Recording-Golang

What happens if my app unexpectedly crashes? Can I still call the same recording endpoints to stop and check the state of the recording?

Answer (score 0):

If an app integrated with cloud recording crashes, the recording session is not affected. You can continue to use the original resource ID and recording ID to control the recording instance, such as to query recording status or stop recording.

If a session is being recorded, you may need to add a heartbeat check to the server, to kill the record if there's no heartbeat in x time for example.